# Replace character in string in Zend Studio

Tags: php, regex, zend-studio

I have some codes like that:

```
$this->translate('ADMIN_CLIENT_USER_MEMBERSHIP_DATA');
$this->translate('ADMIN_CLIENT_USER_MEMBERSHIP_NO_DATA');
```

Now I want to replace the "_" character with "-" over all my sources.

```
$this->translate('ADMIN-CLIENT-USER-MEMBERSHIP-DATA');
$this->translate('ADMIN-CLIENT-USER-MEMBERSHIP-NO-DATA');
```

Can I use the search and replace mask of Zend Studio with regular expressions? What do I have to insert?

Comment: Why *regex*? Replacing `_` with `-` does not require a regex-based replacement feature. What have you tried and what did not work?

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace `_` inside `$this->translate('` and `');` only? Then try `(?:\$this->translate\('|(?!^)\G)(?:(?!'\);)[^_])*\K_` to replace with `-`.

Comment: I hoped it worked for you, thus posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to replace `_` inside `$this->translate('` and `');` only, use

```
(?:\$this->translate\('|(?!^)\G)(?:(?!'\);)[^_])*\K_
```

and replace with `-`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hG9uG7/1)

The `(?:\$this->translate\('|(?!^)\G)` will match the starting part, `$this->translate('`, or the end of the previous match, `(?:(?!'\);)[^_])*` will match any text other than the trailing delimiter, `\K` will omit the whole text matched so far and `_` will match `_`.